# Which cryptographic tool can be used to prove that a program passes a certain test?

Tags: hash, zero-knowledge-proofs

Let's say I have a smart contract located at an address `A`, and another smart contract that runs tests on `A` located at `A'`.  `A` may contain a reference to this test contract and have a function like `runTests` that runs `A'` using the bytecode of `A`.

My question is: is there a way to prove that `A` passed the test, so that the test need not be run again?  I mean, suppose `A` stores a variable called `passedTest` and this is set to `true`.  We would just need to take the contract owner's word for it that the test was passed.  But could there be some sort of hash that `passedTest` could be set to, such that no one could doubt that the test was passed?